# Changing the color of title bar (Non Client Area)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, c++-cli

First let me say I know that it's bad form and that this area should be left to be user preferences. I also know this can be done easily with third party tools like DevExpress if you can afford to go that route. I don't really want to make a borderless form because that strips all functionality from the form and you lose things like minimize/maximize fade transitions.

Despite all of the above, is there a reliable and reasonably accessible way to change the color of the application title bar in WinForms or WPF? Some examples of programs that seem to do this are GitHub desktop, Firefox and Visual Studio. After a lot of research I found a way that sort of works but it's not quite right.

The solution I found seems to use this approach: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx)

This also seems relevant: [Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](http://www.geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx)

The C# code I have found is here: [How to add a control to the Non client area of a custom form.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/349d5d86-3b59-4116-9c5b-f5240f1bed4d/how-to-add-a-control-to-the-non-client-area-of-a-custom-form?forum=winforms)

After a lot of research this is the closest I've been able to get experimenting with the code found there. However, there are a lot of issues. For one thing when you maximize the program there is a 1 pixel area at the top where the program doesn't touch the monitor edge. Also, the borders of the program still show on full screen when they shouldn't.
The title bar has no title and the minimize and maximize buttons have no hover animations.

Any ideas or is this just something we have to live with in WinForms/WPF?
I know it is easy to do in UWP.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See this GitHub project: [MaterialSkin](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin). Also: [SetWindowTheme (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827.aspx), [DisableProcessWindowsGhosting() (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: MaterialSkin seems to lack some form functionality (dock to sides, minimize/maximize animations). I tried SetWindowTheme but had problems with it reverting to a default theme during some actions. Good suggestions though.

Comment: Best bet set `FormBoarderStyle` to `None` and create your own bar + animations.